# how do I figure out what is_image means in file.is_image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a plugin in which `file.is_image` is used. Somewhere, I reckon is_image ought to be defined. How do I find out what it is defined to?

I'd reckon it should be something like "$is_image =" or something like that, I'm not great with JavaScript syntax etc.

Comment: Impossible to answer really - it's somewhere in the source code (obviously) ... look e.g. for occurrences of `this.is_image` or just plain `is_image`

Comment: It is a property (member) of an object, but whether set on creating the object or in a later assignment, we can't tell. Most likely "_something_.is_image = ", but it might be done in other ways. It certainly won't be "$is_image" - that would be assigning a different variable called "$is_image" ($ is not a special character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you already searched the plugin code itself and didn't find it?

If you have Firefox, the [Firebug add-on](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) let you search all loaded scripts, so just search for the word is_image and you'll find it.
Same with Chrome as far as I remember.

For IE you'll probably need external tool but the idea is the same: search through all the loaded scripts in the page.